# How to display the date format in android?

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

```
String date="21-04-2013";
```

In my android application
Here i want to display the date in the following format like "21" is a separate string and month is like "Apr" as a separate string and year is like "13"as a separate string without using String functions.Can anybody plz give some suggestions to convert in this format?any date function is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class for parsing the date string. In order to end up separate strings without using string functions, you'll probably need multiple formatters for the output too. It would look somewhat like this:

```
String date = "21-04-2013";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // input date
Date outDate = dateFormatter.parse(date);

SimpleDateFormat dayFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd"); // output day
SimpleDateFormat monthFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM"); // output month
SimpleDateFormat yearFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yy"); // output year

String day = dayFormatter.format(outDate);
String monthy = monthFormatter.format(outDate);
String year = yearFormatter.format(outDate);
```

If you were to use `String.split()`, you could get rid of at least two of the formatters in above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the class you'll need: [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Examples are provided in the link, but in short, you'll first need to parse the date, and then format the date again.